# How does MP4client choose representations when playing from a local storage for a hevc-coded tile-based stream which uses SRD?

Tags: video, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, hevc, 360-virtual-reality

Can MP4client change the quality of each tile (select the representation of each tile) based on the viewport. If so how we determine the viewport? By moving around in the gui?
Following you see how I am generating the tile-based video which I wanna play locally (so no discussion on bandwidth):

```
kvazaar -i Dance_Left_1920x960.yuv --input-res 1920x960 -o Dance_Left_1920x960_rep1.hvc --tiles 3x3 --slices tiles --mv-constraint frametilemargin -q 22 --input-fps 30

kvazaar -i Dance_Left_1920x960.yuv --input-res 1920x960 -o Dance_Left_1920x960_rep2.hvc --tiles 3x3 --slices tiles --mv-constraint frametilemargin -q 37 --input-fps 30

MP4Box -add Dance_Left_1920x960_rep1.hvc:split_tiles -fps 30 -new Dance_Left_1920x960_rep1.mp4

MP4Box -add Dance_Left_1920x960_rep2.hvc:split_tiles -fps 30 -new Dance_Left_1920x960_rep2.mp4

MP4Box -dash 1000 -profile live -out Dance_Left_1920x960.mpd Dance_Left_1920x960_rep1.mp4 Dance_Left_1920x960_rep2.mp4
```

Now when I am playing this mpd by MP4client always representation 2 is chosen for all tiles and all segments (which is the representation with the lower bitrate)

And if MP4client cannot detect the viewport how can I force it to select specific representations for each tile?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

mp4client -gui your mpd
it can use -gui choose rou

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks